# SilverStripe. How to redirect from www.domainName to domainName?

Tags: redirect, silverstripe

I'm looking to find the reverse of the method:

`Director::forceWWW();`

My main domain should be 
domainName.com without www.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3dgoo's solution is faster since it does not involve any php but I did...

```
class PreventWWW extends DataExtension {
    public static function stopWWW() {
        if(!(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'www') !== 0)) {
            $destURL = str_replace(Director::protocol() .'www.', Director::protocol() , 
                Director::absoluteURL($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
            header("Location: $destURL", true, 301);
            die("<h1>Your browser is not accepting header redirects</h1>"
                . "<p>Please <a href=\"$destURL\">click here</a>");
        }
    }
}
```

in yml config:

```
Director:
  extensions:
    - PreventWWW
```

since I set it just on live-env I had this in _config.php

```
PreventWWW::stopWWW();
```

It should also be possible to set it dependent on environment (live/dev/stage) in yml per "Only". See here..
http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/configuration

Comment: If you're using apache you should use 3dgoo's solution as its much faster. A few notes on this solution if you choose to use it: This will break if you run it on the command line so it should be updated to check (Director::is_cli()). Also, you don't need to add the yaml extension or extend DataExtension as this is just a static method - Director is never instantiated so the extension will never be applied anyway.

Comment: @micmania1  you are right all over :) about the speed I also stated this in the top of my initial answer and the second one - outch :( at least someone noticed – so I'll update.

Answer (score 2):

There is no SilverStripe function to redirect all www links to non www links.

Instead, you can write a `.htaccess` `RewriteRule` to do this.

In your website root `.htaccess` file add the following code under the existing `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
...

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
    RewriteEngine On

    ### Redirect www links to non www links ###

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domainName\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) http://domainName.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    ...
```