# Silverstripe SEO URL - redirect

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, seo, silverstripe

1. How can I make SilverStripe always redirect to a URL with www.
   For example: Someone types in the url http://domain.de/about-us. They should be redirected to http://**www**.domain.de/about-us
   Is there a code for the `_config.php` to set the redirection?
2. There are several domains for one project. How can I make SilverStripe always redirect to the main domain. For example: someone types in the url **büüd.de**/about-us -> they should always be redirected to the main domain **www.bueued.de**/about-us

Answer (score 5):

in _config.php

```
Director::forceWWW();
```

You also can set it per yml but since you have to flush before it takes effect, it can get ugly to disable it (manually delete silverstripe-cache) in cases when the www-domain does not work.

To use one domain I usually use a htaccess-rule.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain3.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain4.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.ch/$1 [r=301,L]
```

This post is related:
[SilverStripe. How to redirect from www.domainName to domainName?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26021385/silverstripe-how-to-redirect-from-www-domainname-to-domainname)

Comment: Thank you! But now im redirected to the url www.bueued.de/framework/main.php?url=/  when i type büüd.de.

Comment: It depends where you put it in your .htaccess. Just below the line with composer should work. https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-installer/blob/3.1/.htaccess#L34